# Visual Basic Json File Updater

Tags: php, json, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am having issues with the follwing code.

```
Public Async Function update_launcher() As Task
        Dim jsonGetter As JsonGetter = New JsonGetter()
        Dim jArray As JArray = jsonGetter.get_array_from_api("http://www.example.com/json.php")
        Dim count As Integer = jArray.Count
        Dim num As Integer = 0
        For Each current As JToken In jArray
            num += 1
            Me._mainWindow.UpdateAvancementLabel(String.Concat(New Object()() {"Updating file ", num, " of ", count}))
            If Me.GetMD5HashFromFile(current("filename").ToString()) <> current("hash").ToString() AndAlso (current("platform").ToString() = "windows" OrElse current("platform").ToString() = "all") Then
                Dim webClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
                AddHandler webClient.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf Me.Completed
                AddHandler webClient.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Me.ProgressChanged
                Dim uriString As String = "http://www.example.com/download/" + current("downloadpath")
                Await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri(uriString), current("filename").ToString())
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

The errors I get off of this piece of code are mainly from the `Me._mainWindow` line and the `Dim uriString As String` line.

This is supposed to read off of a json.php file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "filename":"update/Launcher.exe",
    "downloadpath":"update/Launcher.exe",
    "hash":" ",
    "platform":"windows"
  },
  {
    "filename":"update/Launcher",
    "downloadpath":"update/Launcher",
    "hash":" ",
    "platform":"linux"
  },
  {
    "filename":"update/Launcher",
    "downloadpath":"update/Launcher",
    "hash":" ",
    "platform":"darwin"
  }
]
```

`"hash"` is just the MD5 hash.

If you need any more details, let me know.

```
**Line 8:**
Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'.

Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'.

Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'.

Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'.

**Line 13:**
Operator '+' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Newtonsoft.Json.LingJToken'.
```

Comment: please provide an error message itself, also is it possible to shrink down exmaple code and provide minimal example demonsrating specific issue?

Comment: @Geradlus_RU All parts of the code shown work together, and sorry! Heres the errors i get from the code (Sorry if it doesn't look right)

Comment: I'm not well at `vb.net` myself, but error message quite self-explaining for me. Likely you need some type cast.

Comment: I guess ill try to figure this out.. May take me a few weeks but i have never seen these errors anywhere else, in the same case i get them..

Comment: can you try to replace `String.Concat(New Object()() {"Updating file ", num, " of ", count})` with `String.Concat("Updating file ", num.ToString(), " of ", count.ToString())` (or even `"Updating file " & num & " of " & count`) in `Me._mainWindow.UpdateAvancementLabel(…)` and see will it eliminate at least some errors?

Comment: Why is this tagged in php?